# AngularJS directive not being trigged on manual change to a field value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got an input field and a button that manually updates the input field with a value. The field also has a directive that monitors changes for error handling.

When typing into the input field, the directive triggers just fine. When the button is pressed to manually update the input field, the directive does not get triggered, and I can't figure out why. This is causing my validation to not update, sometimes causing an error to persist when the value is actually not an error.

Here is the input field in question:

```
<input testchange type="text" name="hello" ng-model="formData.hello"/>
```

Here is the button to update the value:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="formData.hello = 'hello world!';">update text</a>
```

Here is the directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('testchange', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
            console.log('value changed to ' + viewValue);
            scope.history.push(viewValue);
        })
      }
    }
});
```

I have made a simple example of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/gakman/7zF9j/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `formatter` in the case when you are updating the model value from button click. Understand your are updating model now not the view when you set `formData.hello='hello world'`.

You need to create a `formatter` and push it into `$formatters` collection on ngModelController. See documentation http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

See my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/N57JM/